# Tcp Gateway exception during repsonse message

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, tcpclient

I'm using spring-integration-ip-4.3.12.

To control an audio device I send some commands, like `setVolumeValue`/`getVolumeValue` or `setMuteState`/`getMuteState` to this device via an Ethernet interface. For the communication I use the `spring-integration-ip`.

I create an tcp client (TcpConfig.java) and I send the messages over an `MessagingGateway` (TcpCommunicationHandler.java) to an external Tcp - Server. 
The command begins with a `0x02` sign for the SET - Commands and `0x04` sign for the GET - Commands and all of them end with a `0x03`. The response message has the same ending sing. For that I include an `ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer` for a **Serializer** and **Deserializer**.

Now, when I send some messages by pushing on a button. After that I get an Error Message. See below.

Please can you help me to find the reason for this exception?

TcpConfig.java:

```
      @Bean
      public AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        final String hostName = configuration.getHostName();
        final int port = configuration.getPort();
        LOGGER.debug("[cx.service.crestron] TcpNetClientConnectionFactory trying to connect to {}:{}", hostName, port);
        return new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(hostName, port);
      }

      @Bean
      @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toTcp")
      public MessageHandler tcpOutGate(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("[cx.service.crestron] creating new TcpOutboundGateway as MessageHandler..");
        final TcpOutboundGateway gate = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        connectionFactory.setSerializer(serializer());
        connectionFactory.setDeserializer(serializer());
        connectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);
        gate.setRequiresReply(true);
        gate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return gate;
      }

      @Bean
      public ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer serializer() {
        return new ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer((byte) 0x03);
      }
```

TcpCommunicationHandler.java

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "toTcp")
public interface TcpCommunicationHandler extends AutoCloseable, Closeable {

  public abstract byte[] executeCommand(final String command);

}
```

Error Log:

```
2017-11-17 16:36:29.111 ERROR 1656 --- [JavaFX Application Thread] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Tcp Gateway exception

org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:79)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:449)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:422)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:478)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:433)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:424)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
```

Comment: Firewall problems?

Comment: @Neil Patrao thanks for review

Comment: @Andremoniy No, i have already check this.

Comment: `Timed out waiting for response`. Are you sure that the server replies to your commands and that is not a one-way communication? https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-adapters

Comment: @ArtemBilan What is unusual about that is that somtimes i get the right response. Is it possible that each command are send too quickly to the device so that i get a false response back?

Comment: Well, that's not on the `TcpOutboundGateway` side. It is blocking and you can send concurrent request only from the separate thread. So, each request gets only its own response. The problem really might be on the server side with the concurrency. But I'm afraid we can do nothing on the matter from the Framework perspective on the client side. You should consult with the server about scenarios you are mentioning and about lost replies. If you say that, it definitely sounds for me as a race condition on the server side.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks a lot. But can i prevent this concurrency? It test this scenario with an external tcp client software and whit this software i get alway the right responses by sending the commands one after the other.

Comment: And when i set the <code> setSingleUse </code> parameter to false, i get the same exception.

Comment: A timeout means either the peer didn't respond, or it didn't include the expected termination character. DEBUG logging might help, but the best debugging tool would be a network monitor like wireshark.

Comment: Yes, I was going to suggest `setSingleUse(false)`. So, if that doesn't work as well, then it is definitely something wrong on server... Although you can try to `synchronized` the service method which calls the `@MessagingGateway` for that TCP communication. This way you will ensure a single-thread behavior around the `TcpOutboundGateway`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your help. What i have read i think also that it is a server problem. I have the communication monitored with wireshark like @GaryRussell said but i don't know how to read the result. Can i add the stored result here?

Comment: Filter the capture with `tcp.port==xxxx` (your port). Look in the window for the request and response, looking for the `0x03` in the reply packet. You can also right click on a packet then "Follow | TCP stream". Then select `Hex Dump` to see the request and reply.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell. 
After the evaluation of the requests and replies i recognize that when i send a command, that the reply is sometimes wrong or is the response of an other command. So i guess that the `MessageTimeoutException` occurs when i send a command and for this command i get not the expected response. 
Can we say that this problem is on the server side? Do you have an idea to solve this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking; if the server is sending the wrong response (or a badly formatted one), how can the client "solve" it? Fix the server.

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought it's possible that the client sends two commands at the same time and then he waits for the response from the second command, but the server sends the command from the first command. 
But wireshark shows me that everything is right at the client side. 
Thanks for your help